# How can I use when, then and otherwise with multiple conditions in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have a data set with three columns. Column A is to be checked for strings. If the string matches `foo` or `spam`, the values in the same row for the other two columns `L` and `G` should be changed to `XX`. For this I have tried the following.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg",],
        "L": ["A54", "A12", "B84", "C12"],
        "G": ["X34", "C84", "G96", "L6",],
    }
)
print(df)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ L   ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ foo  ┆ A54 ┆ X34 │
│ ham  ┆ A12 ┆ C84 │
│ spam ┆ B84 ┆ G96 │
│ egg  ┆ C12 ┆ L6  │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

expected outcome

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ L   ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ foo  ┆ XX  ┆ XX  │
│ ham  ┆ A12 ┆ C84 │
│ spam ┆ XX  ┆ XX  │
│ egg  ┆ C12 ┆ L6  │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I tried this

```
df = df.with_column(
    pl.when((pl.col("A") == "foo") | (pl.col("A") == "spam"))
    .then((pl.col("L")= "XX") & (pl.col( "G")= "XX"))
    .otherwise((pl.col("L"))&(pl.col( "G")))
)
```

However, this does not work. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For setting multiple columns to the same value you could use:

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col("A").is_in(["foo", "spam"]))
     .then(pl.lit("XX"))
     .otherwise(pl.col("L", "G"))
     .name.keep()
)
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ L   ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ foo  ┆ XX  ┆ XX  │
│ ham  ┆ A12 ┆ C84 │
│ spam ┆ XX  ┆ XX  │
│ egg  ┆ C12 ┆ L6  │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

[`.is_in()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_in.html#polars.Expr.is_in) can be used instead of multiple `== x | == y` chains.

Comment: How can you do such an operation if you need to access the column value inside the lambda ? For exemple : `lambda col: {"L": pl.col("..."), "G": pl.col("...")}.get(col.name)`

Comment: @mlisthenewcool `col` is the column (pl.Series), so you can e.g. `{"L": col.str.to_uppercase(), ...}`